# My minecraft server issue

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-mods

I decided to get a mod for my Minecraft Realm. I downloaded Minecraft Forge and the mod. I reopened Minecraft, tried to enter my Realm, and it wasn't there. Red letters appeared on my screen, stating:

> TRY RESTARTING MINECRAFT

I restarted Minecraft several times.  I removed every single trace of the mod and Minecraft Forge. I tried again and it still didn't work. I could not log onto a non-Realms server, either. I repaired Minecraft on Mojang's website, but it still doesn't work!

Comment: Can you tell us everything that was on the error screen? If we know that we can help you better.

Comment: Have you reinstalled Minecraft?

Comment: No, i havent tried that. I will go reinstall it right now. Also, It said Error, Try restarting minecraft.

Comment: it didnt work.... i dont know what to do. I am thinking maybe someone hacked my account and turned off going online through parental controls, but i dont know how to acess that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Happened To Me Yesterday, Try Switching Accounts, Switching Back And Re-Update Minecraft And Reset Your Computer